# How do I test for integers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, integer

I'm writing a program that will calculate factorials of integers. However, the part I'm stuck on is if someone enters a non-integer such as `1.3`, I'd like to be able to test the input and display  `"The number you have entered is not an integer"`

Comment: Related: see `doc gamma` for the equivalent of factorial for non-integers.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html) function, which returns the remainder after division. All integers are divisible by `1`.  So a good test for non-integer would be

```
integerTest=~mod(value,1);
```

This returns `0` if `value` is not an integer and `1` if it is. You can then use this as a conditional to reject non-integer user inputs.

Comment: Clever idea! In Matlab R2014a it's viceversa, however. mod(text,1) is 0 if a number is integer or not.

Comment: mod will not work with vector as an input argument. e.g mod([3 2],1) will return [0 0], which will be evaluated as true (Integer Value).

Answer (score 22):

Here is another variation (you can see it being used in [ISIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/isind.html) function: `edit isind.m`):

```
integerTest = ( x == floor(x) );
```

On my machine, it is faster than the other proposed solutions:

```
%# create a vector of doubles, containing integers and non-integers
x = (1:100000)';                       %'
idx = ( rand(size(x)) < 0.5 );
x(idx) = x(idx) + rand(sum(idx),1);

%# test for integers
tic, q1 = ~mod(x, 1); toc
tic, q2 = x==double(uint64(x)); toc
tic, q3 = x==floor(x); toc

%# compare results
assert( isequal(q1,q2,q3) )
```

Timings:

```
Elapsed time is 0.012253 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.014201 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.005665 seconds.
```

Comment: `round` appears to be even faster than `floor`.  Just FYI.

Comment: @KronoS: I'd say both are in the same order of magnitude, the difference is negligible. Here is a another comparison using the [TIMEIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798) function: http://pastebin.com/xMEmSi5h

Comment: @ChristopherBarber: ok, then we should add `isfinite` to catch Inf and NaN cases, as in: `integerTest = isfinite(x) & ( x == floor(x) );`

Comment: @ChristopherBarber: and if you really want to be thorough, you should also test numbers are non-complex with `isreal`

Comment: @ChristopherBarber It works in Octave: `Inf==floor(Inf)`
`ans = 1`

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the value to an integer and back to a double and check the result against the original value:

```
>> x = 1.3;
>> x == double(uint64(x))

ans =

     0

>> x = 2;
>> x == double(uint64(x))

ans =

     1
```

Interestingly, [R.M.'s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396551/need-matlab-to-notice-non-integers/5397031#5397031) of using MOD runs faster in a loop and the above casting approach runs faster when vectorized:

```
>> x = rand(100000, 1);
>> tic; for ii = 1:100000; ~mod(x(ii), 1); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.018380 seconds.
>> tic; for ii = 1:100000; x(ii) == double(uint64(x(ii))); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.383020 seconds.
>> tic; ~mod(x, 1); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.005299 seconds.
>> tic; x == double(uint64(x)); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.002971 seconds.
```

Comment: In general, you don't know how large the integer is. The maximum in `uint64` is of order 10^(18). While we can be sure that you can't compute the factorial of something that large (in which case this works), as a general approach, this fails for large numbers.

Comment: This seems a bit ... unmatlabesque.  Use round(), fix(), floor(), or ceil() if you want to make an integer-valued quantity.

Comment: Why the downvote? d'o-o'b is correct about the limit imposed by `uint64` but as he explained this is not an operational limit since computing the factorial of a number near this limit could not be done anyways.

Comment: @nibot: I don't understand your "unmatlabesque" comment. `double` and `uint64` are as much a part of the MATLAB built-in library as the functions you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

`assert(isnumeric(input) && round(input) == input, 'That number is not an integer.')`

You could add other checks, (like for positivity) easily as well.

Edited using `isinteger`. Thanks `@SolarStatistics`, I hadn't noticed they added this functionality.
Edited back to original answer again as `isinteger` isn't appropriate (see comments below).

Comment: "isinteger" is probably not what's wanted, since it checks for an integer TYPE.  The OP probably wants a conditional check like "x - fix(x) == 0" or "x - fix(x) < eps" that works on doubles.

Answer (score 0):

As point out by @nibot *isinteger* tests for the input as an integer TYPE.  Instead you could check to see if rounding *input* returns the same value as *input*. eg:

```
assert(abs(round(input)-input))<eps*2,'That number is not an integer.')
```

for example

```
>> input=1.3;
>> assert(abs(round(input)-input)<eps*2,'That number is not an integer.')
??? That number is not an integer.

>> input=3;
>> assert(abs(round(input)-input)<eps*2,'That number is not an integer.')
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that the provided methods all test for whether the input is a *Gaussian integer*, meaning that the real and imaginary parts are **both** integers. If you need to care about the imaginary part then you need to deal with it separately.

For my applications, inputs with imaginary components shouldn't be considered a valid integer, so I have this:

```
function boolResult = fnIsInteger(input)
    %validate input
    if isempty(input)
        error('Input cannot be empty')
    elseif ~isnumeric(input)
        error('Input must be numeric')
    end

    boolResult = (imag(input) == 0) & (round(input) == input);
end
```

Using b3.'s tests:

```
>> x = rand(100000, 1);
>> tic; for ii = 1:100000; ~mod(x(ii), 1); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.003960 seconds.
>> tic; for ii = 1:100000; fnIsInteger(x(ii)); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.217397 seconds.
>> tic; ~mod(x, 1); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000967 seconds.
>> tic; fnIsInteger(x); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.003195 seconds.
```

The looped call is quite a bit slower mostly due to the function overhead. Replacing the arithmetic expression with ~mod(dataInput, 1) will make it only 50% faster than the code that checks for imaginary parts.

Answer (score -1):

By `double` command, you cannot get the correct answer:

```
>> double(uint64(21/22))
ans =
     1
>> double(uint64(22/22))
ans =
     1
```

also `floor`,`round`,... have problem with such cases:

```
floor(22/22)==21.99999999999999999999999999999999999/22
```

but `mod` seems can distinguish `22/22` and `21.99999999999999999999999999999999999/22`:

```
>> mod(22,22)
ans =
     0
>> (21.99999999999999999999999999999999999/22)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: -1 this does not answer the question of testing for integers.. As for the literal `21.9999...` you entered, it is actually `22`! (you have to be mindful of the limitations of floating-point representation: [tag:floating-point-precision])