# How to select whole numbers in a row and its adjacent numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Good day!

I would like to select the whole numbers in my random data, at the same time it will also choose the adjacent numbers.

For example, I have this raw data

```
A = [0.1    0.2
     0.2    0.1
      1     0.3
     0.3    0.2
     0.4    0.4
      2     0.5]
```

so would like to select the (1, 0.3) and (2, 0.5). then my final ouptut will be,

```
B=  [1 0.3
     2 0.4]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to find the whole integer numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo:
`B=A(sum(mod(A,1),2)==0,:)`

==========  EDIT  ====================

Editing w.r.t. comments, if you are only checking for integers in the first column then you do not need to sum results:
`B=A(mod(A(:,1),1)==0,:)`

Alternative ways would use logicals instead of numericals:
`B=A(all(A==round(A),2),:)`
or if only the 1st column is checked:
`B=A(A==round(A(:,1)),:)`

Comment: This is great! tho, what if the adjacent number is not whole number? then you add the two column it will give decimal numbers. I will edit my raw data to give you insight. Thanks!

Comment: you mean you only want to check the 1st column? in that case it's even simpler: B=A(mod(A(:,1),1)==0,:)

Comment: The `round` method is significantly faster than `mod` (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916862/7328782)). `mod` requires a a division, which is expensive, whereas `round` is rather trivial. `fix` might be even faster.